# Printing out what a user inputs into an HTML form under the forms using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, last question. I have two inputs and only one is printing. I know my jquery is wrong but how can I fix it to print both?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<title>Hello world</title>
<body>
    <form id="games">
First Input:    <input type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Write stuff in me"/><br/>
Second Input:   <input type="text" name="input2" placeholder="And in me"/><br/>
<br/>
<button
```

Comment: You need to close your tag `<h6>`

Comment: Running your html through a validator gives "Error Line 16, Column 7: end tag for "H6" omitted, but its declaration does not permit this"

Comment: I think you want to use `.after()`, not `.append()`.

Comment: The `title` goes within the `head`. Also close the `h6` tag.

Comment: Look at my updated answer below for the answer to your edit 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your `<h6>` tag and then your append will put the div in there but I dont think you can put divs in the `<h>` tags. Try using span instead if you want the text inside the h6.

If you want to add the div after your h6 tag. use jquerys `.after()` function.

```
$('h6').after('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>')
```

Edit based on your edit.

When you click your button your submitting your form which is clearing your page. Just add a preventDefault to stop that from happening...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#printbtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var toAdd = $('input[name=input1]').val();
        $('h6').after('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>')
    });
});
```

Heres a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pk6q4/2/